# running with pytest parametrize fixture I am getting `self` is not defined

Tags: python, pytest

I have this class:

accept.py

```
class AcceptC(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.minimum = 30
        self.maximum = 40
```

and the unittest:

accept_test.py

```
import unittest
import pytest

from app.accept import AcceptC


class TestAcceptC(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.accept = AcceptC()


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "minimum, maximum, expected_min, expected_max", [
        ("13", "5", 30, 40),
        ("30", "40", 30, 40),
    ])
def test_init_returns_correct_results(minimum, maximum, expected_min, expected_max):
    expected_min = self.accept.minimum
    expected_max = self.accept.maximum
    self.assertEqual(minimum, expected_min)
    self.assertEqual(maximum, expected_max)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When running with pytest, I am getting an error:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

I saw also that I cannot use `self` in the test function as argument.

Lastly, is there a way to avoid using:

```
expected_min = self.accept.minimum
expected_max = self.accept.maximum
```

and use immediately `self.accept.minimum`?

If I use `self` as an argument to the test function, it returns:

> fixture 'self' not found

Comment: `def test_init_returns_correct_results` is not inside any class, therefore "self" is not defined

Comment: It's because self if not defined where you're using it. That's the whole answer. Only use names that are defined.

Comment: @ZiTAL:You were right.I had missed the indentation.But still I have error messages..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `self` in your methods (assuming it is a method, if it's a function than you need to make it a method of `TestAcceptC` first) argument list:

```
def test_init_returns_correct_results(minimum, maximum, expected_min, expected_max):
```

should be (I did some additional changes; away from `unittest` and more `pytest`-like):

```
class TestAcceptC():  # no need to subclass unittest

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        # Called when setting up the class
        cls.accept = AcceptC()

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        ["minimum", "maximum", "expected_min", "expected_max"], [
            ("13", "5", 30, 40),
            ("30", "40", 30, 40),
        ])
    def test_init_returns_correct_results(self, minimum, maximum, expected_min, expected_max):
        # difference is here -------------^^^^
        # pytest can use normal asserts here.
        assert self.accept.minimum == expected_min
        assert self.accept.maximum == expected_max
```

Comment: If I use self as an argument, it returns `fixture 'self' not found`

Comment: It's a method of your `TestAcceptC` class, right? It should be if it wants to access it's attribute.

Comment: I am testing the __init__ method of the AcceptC class.And test_init.. is a method of TestAcceptC ,.It is just like the 2 files I have above.

Comment: Hmm, I had wrong indentation that's why I was receiving the previous error.But , using self as an argument gives me `TypeError: test_init_method_returns_correct_results() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'minimum', 'maximum', 'expected_min', and 'expected_max'`

Comment: I think the fixture can't understand the self parameter inside the test function and it expects to have a value?That's why I have this error

Comment: @George I've changed it a bit to make it more pytest-like. At least I had no problems with that function. Could be some weird pytest-unittest interaction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134056/discussion-between-george-and-mseifert).

Answer (score 9):

The problem is simply because of:

```
class TestAcceptC(unittest.TestCase):
```

This inheritance of unittest.TestCase will break 'self' in regards to pytest fixtures.

information: https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.0.1/unittest.html